# How to prevent chrome to freeze tab with my website offering offline functionality

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications

My webpage, allows to download data while online, and then even if offline, You can still work on that web page with no restrictions.
But after chrome started this new freezing tab feature, what is happening is that when I am not on my website tab for some time, and click on it back, chrome will refresh page automatically, and break it.

This can be prevented by changing settings in chrome itself, but user has to do that. Is there some way to prevent this freezing with javascript or page meta maybe ?